# checkbox remain checked after submit laravel

Tags: checkbox, laravel-5.3

I have this simple checkbox.

My problem is, if I select any of the checkbox, it should remain checked after form submission.

```
<label>                                                                
    <input type="checkbox" name="services_offered[]" value="water jet cutting"> Water Jet Cutting</label>
<label>                                                                
    <input type="checkbox" name="services_offered[]" value="plasma cutting"> Plasma Cutting</label>
<label>                                                                
    <input type="checkbox" name="services_offered[]" value="CNC router cutting"> CNC Router Cutting</label>
```

I tried to use my code before but no luck,

```
<?php 
function isChecked($value)
{
    return (!empty($_REQUEST['services_offered']) && in_array($value,$_REQUEST['services_offered']));
}

    <label><input type="checkbox" name="services_offered[]" value="water jet cutting" <?php if(isChecked('water jet cutting')) echo ' checked' ?>> Water Jet Cutting</label>

    <label><input type="checkbox" name="services_offered[]" value="plasma cutting" <?php if(isChecked('plasma cutting')) echo ' checked' ?> > Plasma Cutting</label>

    <label><input type="checkbox" name="services_offered[]" value="CNC router cutting" <?php if(isChecked('CNC router cutting')) echo ' checked' ?>> CNC Router Cutting</label>
```

I want it to convert in "laravel way" but I dont know how.

Hope you understand me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understand you correct but:

The form does not post values of the checkboxes. 
So I made hidden inputs associated with each checkbox and maintain there values with javascript something like:

```
 $("#services_offered").change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            $('#services_offeredHidden').attr('value','1');
        }
        else {
            $('#services_offeredHidden').attr('value','0');
        }
    });
```

In laravel controller I play only with hidden inputs which I get the from Request $request. 
When you return the view from a controller you do like this

```
return view('nameOfView')->with('checkbox',$checkboxValue);
```

and the in the blade you can access the value using:

```
 {{$checkbox}}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you want the "Laravel way" of doing things then I suggest you check out the [HTML package by Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html) for marking up the HTML forms in your view. Also make sure the methods on your controller are receiving a [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests) as it's argument and maybe even checkout [Laravel's built-in Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#form-request-validation) as well.

Note, your current code is very old fashioned so it might take a while to learn how to do things the modern way but stick with it and you will be rewarded.

In your view you will open your form like this:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'foo/bar']) !!}
//
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Your method on the controller that receives the form will look something like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->input('name');

    //
}
```

But in general, because your question is too broad to answer clearly without basically re-writing your code for you, you need to start doing some tutorials to learn Laravel properly. I recommend Jeff Way's video tutorial courses on [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - here is how I solved it:

My blade template rendered a list of checkboxes as html:

```
<label for="sId1"><input type='checkbox' name='sIds[]' id="sId1" value="1"  checked >Draft</label>
<label for="sId2"><input type='checkbox' name='sIds[]' id="sId2" value="2"  checked >Submitted</label>
```

I wanted to a) default them all to checked; and b) preserve their checked/unchecked status between validations.

The key is to use the laravel helper function old() - and to realise the old() function returns an array - so you need to do an in_array(value,old()). You also need to cover when the old() is empty on first load by checking is old()==null:

Here is the blade template snippet I used to do it:

```
@foreach($wfStatusIdsArray as $wfsId=>$statusName)
<label for="sId{{$wfsId}}"><input type='checkbox' @if(old('sIds')==NULL || in_array($wfsId,old('sIds'))) checked @endif name='sIds[]' id="sId{{$wfsId}}" value="{{$wfsId}}">{{$statusName}}</label>
@endforeach
```

There is a bug in this - if ALL checkboxes are cleared, on validation, the checkboxes are reloaded as all ticked. This is fine for my situation so I have not fixed it. Let me know if you fix that bug!